# How can I have a multiple grouped select with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

By default, this gives me a multiple select by virtue of being a has_many relationship:

```
<%= f.association :tags %>
```

However, I want to group my tags based on a category.  Yet, when I do that, my select becomes a normal select that only allows for one selection.  In other words, the "multiple" attribute on the input goes away.

```
<%= f.association :tags, as: :grouped_select, collection: TagGroup.all, group_method: :tags %>
```

I've tried different suggestions, such as adding `html: {multiple: "multiple"}` or simply `multiple: true`, but neither has any effect.

Am I missing something?  I see no reason why my select can't be a multiple in this case, since all the grouped select should be doing is adding `optgroup` tags.

Here's the tag I get without doing a grouped select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="select optional" name="news_story[tag_ids][]" id="news_story_tag_ids">
```

And with the grouped select:

```
<select class="grouped_select optional" name="news_story[tag_ids]" id="news_story_tag_ids">
```

It also seems to mangle the name attribute, though I haven't tested if that poses a problem.

EDIT: I would settle for the `grouped_collection_select` helper, but that also does not provide an options hash for adding attributes.
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Comment: Have you looked at ```grouped_options_for_select``` by chance? http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_options_for_select     you can build the select multiple the regular way and pass it the already built options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own.

This produced the correct output:

```
<%= f.association :tags, as: :grouped_select, collection: TagGroup.all, group_method: :tags, input_html: { :multiple => true } %>
```

The key part being:

```
input_html: { :multiple => true }
```